# ROS and MatLab support, IPC-Bridge

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

So far as I know ROS does not support MatLab. I wonted to use online MatlAb with ROS. So to subscribe or publish a ROS topic to Matlab. For example I have calculated some parameters with ROS and wont online to import some MAtLab function, like find the minimum value of the ROS output parameters. Till now the only way was to save the parameters in a txt file and later on offline use MatLab. I found that exist IPC-Bridge package to communicate with ROS. Is the communication online??Im using ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 10.4. IS IPC-Bridge supported on ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 10.04??IS there any tutorial how to install, use and some example??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48693/ros-and-matlab-support,-ipc-bridge/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If by online you mean communication with a running MATLAB instance, then yes online communication is permitted.

See the [page here](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Emeam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge) that provides examples and instructions..

There are also answers to questions here on answers.ros like [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/45838/error-when-installing-ipc-bridge-for-ros-and-matlab/) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/45838/error-when-installing-ipc-bridge-for-ros-and-matlab/), but the tag is the key to building from the experience of [others before us](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:ipc_bridge_ros/page:1/).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1